# Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in....gets me crazy

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have loaded the extensions...

```
extension=php_gettext.dll

extension=php_mbstring.dll

extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it

extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

....in my php.in file as say in most of forums but I always get the same error!!!

I have updated to mySQL5.5 & PHP 5.4

¿what else can i do to solve the problem?¿can anyone help me?

I'm a bit tired of trying thousands of possibilities and always get the same message :)

THank you

Comment: Are you sure that you've enabled them in the right php.ini file? Are you sure you've restarted your webserver afterwards? Check the output from php.ini to see what ini file is actually being used

Comment: Assuming you see this message in your phpmyadmin screen, try restarting your server and clear your cookies. The message you see might just be a cached copy.

Comment: @MarkBaker: How many php.ini files can I have?? I only know one php.ini file ¿?

Comment: As many php.ini files as you can physically create on a box; but PHP will only use one at a time, typically you'll have at least 2 (on for the web SAPI, one for the CLI), but you may find residual files left behind from previous versions of PHP.... knowing which one is being used by your scripts is pretty important. phpinfo will tell you which one is being used

Comment: Create an empty php file and type in it: <?php phpinfo(); ?> - open that in a browser and check if you are using the right php.ini

Comment: OK!!!
You were right @mark, my **PHP.ini file was in C:\windows\system32(as I did in my old PHP4) not in C:\PHP\(in PHP5)**, didn't find PHP.ini and it caused error¡¡¡

It only was a little error(config PHP4!=PHP5) which gots me crazy¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡...........thanks so much mark:D